# Images side-floating when they have to be centered on phone mode

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, alignment

On desktop mode, one `img` is floating left and the other one is floating right.

When I'm on phone mode, I try to align them on the center, but they stay `floating`.

What am I doing wrong?

Below you can see my code so far.

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <header>
        <h3 class="right">¿Tienes la pantalla rota?</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        <img class="image left" src="images/moviles/apple/ip4/iphone4.png"/ alt="Cambiar la pantalla iPhone 4, DoctorSmart">
        ¿La pantalla de tu iPhone está rota o tiene manchas extrañas?Tiene solución. DoctorSmart te instalará una completamente nueva para que puedas volver a disfrutar de tu iPhone como el primer día.
    </p>
    <p>DoctorSmart utiliza repuestos de la máxima calidad, ademas de ofrecerte 3 meses de garantía. Para que no tengas que preocuparte por tu smartphone</p>
    <p class="precio">Cambia la  pantalla para tu iPhone 4 por solo 35€, Gastos de recogida y entrega incluidos</p>
    <footer>
        <ul class="actions right">
            <li><a href="#" class="button">Arréglalo</a></li>

        </ul>
    </footer>
</section>

<section>
    <header>
        <h3 class="left">¿El cristal trasero esta roto?</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        <img class="image right" src="images/moviles/apple/ip4/iphone4back.png" alt="Cambiar cristal trasero iphone 4, DoctoSmart"/>
        Si la parte trasera de tu precioso iPhone 4 tiene arañazos, o esta rota y resquebrajada no te preocupes. DoctorSmart puede cambiar el cristal trasero de tu iPhone en un santiamén, para que vuelvas a fardar de movil.
    </p>
    <p>DoctorSmart utiliza repuestos de la máxima calidad, ademas de ofrecerte 3 meses de garantía. Para que no tengas que preocuparte por tu smartphone</p>
    <p class="precio">El cambio de cristal trasero para tu iPhone 4 sale por solo 35€, gastos de recogida y entrega incluidos</p>
    <footer>
        <ul class="actions right">
            <li><a href="#" class="button">Arréglalo</a></li>       
        </ul>
    </footer>
</section>
```

**DESKTOP CSS:**

```css
/* Image */

.image
{
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
}

.image img
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.image.centered
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.centered img
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}

.image.featured
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.left
{
    float: left;
    margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
}

.image.right
{
    float: right;
    margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
}
```

**PHONE CSS:**

```css
.image.left
{
    float: none;
    left: 0px
    right:0px

}

.image.right
{
    float: none;
    margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
}
```

Comment: what are the media queries that was used to include the css and what order is the css included (phone first or desktop first)..

Comment: i am using SKELETON, and the first  stylesheet to be attached is style.css, then style-mobile.css

Comment: This is the HTML code:  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <noscript>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
  </noscript>

Answer (score 0):

No need to split your **CSS** in two files. You can target different view ports using media queries. Try the below:

```
.image {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
}

.image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.image.centered {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.centered img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}

.image.featured {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.image.left {
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        float: left;
        margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
    }
}

.image.right {
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        float: right;
        margin: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
    }
}
```